# Implement an interface on a struct inside a function

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a piece of code which accepts an `io.Writer` implementation as an argument.

```
func printSummary(writer io.Writer) {
    // Implementation of the 'printSummary' method goes here.
}
```

Now, I can easily create a mock to create a unit test.
This would look like the following:

```
type ioWriterMock struct {
    writtenBytes []byte
}

func (writer *ioWriterMock) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    writer.writtenBytes = append(writer.writtenBytes, p...)

    return 0, nil
}
```

However, this does mean that I need to declare my mock outside of my unit test, which makes it available in the whole package.

I would like to create my test, and that everything that my test depends on is inside the test.
This for the simple reason that everything is in one place and that I don't need to scan different files in my package to find the different parts that are required for my test.

In a unit test, you can create a struct and define functions.
This is done using the following approach:

```
func TestParse(t *testing.T) {
    type utCase struct {
        name                 string
        summary              string
        expectedWrittenBytes []byte
    }

    createUtCase := func(name, summary string, expWrittenBytes []byte) utCase {
        retVal := new(utCase)
        retVal.name = name
        retVal.summary = summary
        retVal.expectedWrittenBytes = expWrittenBytes

        return *retVal
    }
}
```

So embedding the `io.Writer` mock in the unit test can be done in the following way:

```
func TestParse(t *testing.T) {
    type ioWriterMock struct {
        writtenBytes []byte
    }
}
```

One thing which I don't find is how I'm able to implement the `io.Writer` interface on that type.

Comment: You cannot do this. Methods must be defined at the package level.

Comment: *"which makes it available in the whole package."* if you declare it in a file ending with `_test.go` it will be available only to other test files in that package, normal files won't be able to access it. *"I would like to create my test, and that everything that my test depends on is inside the test."* this is not possible in Go, not if by test you mean a function. Method declarations are "top-level" declaration, that means that they need to be placed at the package level, it's not possible to have a method declaration at any other level below that.

Comment: Although if all you need is an `io.Writer`, then a) it's not really a mock, as it's a full implementation. b) use `bytes.Buffer` or similar. No need to create your own type.

Comment: As an alternative you could also just move your test utilities/helpers to their own package, like for example: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/, then only the file that imports the package would have access to its members.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @mkopriva, put the `ioWriterMock` definition next to the `TestParse` function in the `_test.go` file. In go, it is not allowed to put the definition of a function inside another function. You can only define the struct type in a function.

By defining the `ioWriterMock` type and `Write` method inside the test file, it will only be visible during test execution. It won't be present and thus visible when using the package outside of a test.

Also, considering the given example, a `bytes.Buffer` would be a good free substitute to your `ioWriterMock` as suggested by @Flimzy.

Comment: If I have several test files for a package, I might need to look in different test files to find my mock object. That was the reason I asked this particular question. Would like to avoid this issue ...